# Difference between these two probability statements?

Tags: probability

The issue is determining the probability of the events in terms of $P(A)$, $P(B)$, $P(A∩B)$ given events $A, B$.

My question is regarding the difference b/w these two statements..

- Either $A$ or $B$ or both.
- At least one of $A$ or $B$.

Aren't they both $P(A∪B)$?

Comment: You’re right: they are.

Comment: This seems more like logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, they both represent the same event $A\cup B$

Answer (score 1):

99% of the time in probability, "or" means the (inclusive) union denoted by $\cup$. Sometimes an exclusive "or" is used, and it would be denoted by $\triangle$; this one is called the symmetric difference.

$$
A \triangle B = (A - B) \cup (B-A)
$$

So an element is in the symmetric difference if its in one of the guys, but not both.